# Which 12.04 download should I choose for x86 based pc (32-bit) with an AMD processor?

Tags: installation

The ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso will not work with my processor. I tried to run it from my Live USB stick and a message appears `this cannot be installed with your processor`.

Which alternative download should I choose for an *x86 based PC with a x86 Family 6 Model 6 Stepping 2 authentic AMD processor running at 1254 Mhz*?

Proceeding to the alternative versions, I am given the following options:

- ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent
- ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso.torrent
- ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
- ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent
- ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent
- ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso.torrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the CPU doesn't have [PAE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAE) support. `ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso.torrent` should do the job, although it's a text based installer. You could also install 11.10 and then upgrade to 12.04, or go with Xubuntu.

Comment: I don't understand text based installer. Does that mean no GUI and I'll need to know the commands to type, as at the terminal? Not sure I have the skills yet?

Comment: mikewhatever- your answer has been extraordinarily helpful. Instead of downloading another version of Ubuntu, I'm just going to swap out this processor with a better one and install Ubuntu from my Live USB stick. I'm pressed for time. I need this PC running again to complete a project with a deadline.                     Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are most welcome. It's a good thing to have so many CPUs around. In case you change your mind about the Alternate CD, check out the [HOWTO](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p2.html).

Answer (score 0):

No need to fret. The alternate install (ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386) is text-based in that there won't be pretty graphics to choose your location and pictures to entertain you during the install. It will, however, guide you through all the install steps and give you choices to make. Those steps and choices are exactly the same as the graphical installer, so you should have no problem with it.

So, onto the installation.

First, download the torrent for that installer: http://ubuntu.virginmedia.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso.torrent

Then, check the MD5SUM. It should match this string: `bcee4c03b704a9b62988505b7d8f3069`, as reported here: http://ubuntu.virginmedia.com/releases/precise/MD5SUMS

To do that, open a command line (CTRL+ALT+T), navigate to wherever you downloaded the torrent, and type this: `md5sum ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso` and hit Enter. (Hint: you can write `md5sum ubu` and hit TAB. If it's the only file that starts with that word in that directory, it will auto-complete the file name)

If the string matches, we can move on the next step, if not, throw that away and download it again.

Once the string matches, create an install CD or install USB and just install as you normally do.